# Where can I find good Company of Heroes replays?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I'm interested in improving my Company of Heroes play. Back when I played Warcraft 3, I watched pro replays to increase my understanding of strategy, tactic and game mechanics as well as to get new ideas.

Is there a place to find professional CoH games to watch, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Replays Company of Heroes](http://www.gamereplays.org/companyofheroes/replays.php?game=25)

Regular and expert replays.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch them on Youtube.
KrebsCoHo does some awesome casts, Innuki isn't too shabby either.

I think gamereplays.org also show game replays as well, but I prefer watching the casts of Krebs and Innuki, as they provide running commentary on the game itself, tactics and random chit chat.